# Ajax does not work even though I used csrf_token

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a web game project using django

first, when I bring user character data using ajax-get method,

it working fine

```
(function(){
    $("document").ready(function(){

        $get_id = $('#character');

        //현재 로그인 된 유저가 케릭터를 갖고 있는지 확인하는 코드
        $user_has_character = $(".data").data("hasCharacter");


        /*****************************
         * when user have character
         * ***************************/
        if($user_has_character=="True"){

            get_gamestart_api_url = '/api/gamestart/data/';

            //게임 화면 태그
            $scene = $('#scene');

            $scene.css("background", "url(../static/images/game/loadingBackground.jpg) no-repeat");

        /*****************************
         * 
         * json will get user's character data
         * 
         * **************************/
        $.ajax({

            method:'GET',
            url:get_gamestart_api_url,

        }).done(function(data){
                character = data[0].character[0]
                $get_id.append("<li class='stat'> 케릭터 닉네임: "+character.nickname+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 레벨: "+character.level+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 직업: "+character.job+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 공격력: "+character.status.attack_point+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 수비력: "+character.status.defence_point+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 체력: "+character.status.health+"</li>",
                    "<li class='stat'> 케릭터 마나: "+character.status.mana+"</li>",
                    );
            });


    }else{
        /*********************
         * When the user does not have a character
         ********************/

    }

});
})();
```

So, I think $.ajax doesn't have any problem,

and `when user doesn't have character, user must create a character`

```
}else{
     /*********************
     * When the user does not have a character
     ********************/

        //form tag will created
        $get_id.append("<form method='post' action='/'> <input name='nickname' type='text' style='border: 1px solid #ff0000;'><input type='submit' class='btn_character'> </form>");

        $btn_character = $(".btn_character");
        console.log($btn_character);

        //when user click create user button
        $btn_character.on("click", function(event){

            //using jQuery
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                //these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });

            //get input text nickname
            $nickname = $("input[name=nickname]").val();

            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/api/user/characters/',
                data:{
                    nickname:$nickname
                },
            });
        });

    }
```

even though I used jquery csrf_token, when send $.ajax post,
it show error

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /
```

but I can't understand what is problem in my code...

Comment: This is because you requiring a `csrftoken` value but that value has not been generated by the server. It's not included inside your `form`!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @nik_m oh, I'm sorry I solve my issue but I remove '.js' file and rewrite, I can't understand is issue, but I solved my problem

Comment: If my answer helped you to resolve this issue then accepted please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this `script` is inside your HTML **and not in an external `.js`** file you can rewrite this:

```
$get_id.append("<form method='post' action='/'> <input name='nickname' type='text' style='...'><input type='submit' class='btn_character'> </form>");
```

to this:

```
$get_id.append("<form method='post' action='/'>{% csrf token %} <input name='nickname' type='text' style='...'><input type='submit' class='btn_character'> </form>");
```

When you `POST` data to Django, you must post the [`csrf token`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/) along with the other form data. That's the cause of your error.

The `csrf_token` is generated by the server and is injected as a hidden input inside your form.

If this script lives in its own file and you load it in your HTML as: `<script src="path/to/the/script.js"></script>` then you have 2 options:

1. Instead of loading it this way, [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it, so that Django can render this value. For example, you should save it (including the `<script></script>` tags!) as `game_script.html`. Then in your HTML template inject it like this:

   `<body>
       staf here and ...
       ... at the bottom
       {% include 'game_script.html' %}
    </body>`
2. The other option is before creating the form dynamically, make another AJAX request to the server to get a `csrf token` and once you get it, then create the form (inside the `append`) including the `csrf_token` you received.

The easiest solution, however, is not to make a `POST` request to Django but a `GET` one. Simply, change the `method='post'` to `method='get'` and you are good to go. No `csrf tokens` need it.